# How to seacrh from an array store in MySql column with Laravel

Tags: mysql, arrays, laravel, search, eloquent

I have a column in products tables name primary_colors which store data in following format

```
["5","7","11"]
```

when user filter the products and select all the colors suppose

```
primary_color => array:1 [▼
    0 => "5",
    1 => "11"
  ]
```

How to make this search using laravel?

Comment: Would https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#json-where-clauses help?

Answer (score 0):

To search on `products` table the column `primary_colors` in JSON, you can use [`whereJsonContains`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#json-where-clauses). For example:

```
$primaryColors = [5, 11];

$products = DB::table('products')
    ->whereJsonContains('primary_colors', $primaryColors)
    ->get();
```

You just need to watch out for JSON column types support on DB: **MySQL 5.7+, PostgreSQL, SQL Server 2016, and SQLite 3.39.0.**